# Limiting number of instances of windows in an MDI application

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, mdi

I want to restrict the user to create multiple instances of a form in an MDI application.

If one instance of that form is opened it must get focus. If it is not a new instance it must be created.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this.

Create a static Method:

```
public static Form IsFormAlreadyOpen(Type FormType)
{
    foreach (Form OpenForm in System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms)
    {
        if (OpenForm.GetType() == FormType)
            return OpenForm;
    }

    return null;
}
```

And then when you create your child form.

```
frmMyChildForm frmChild1;

 if ((frmChild1 = (frmMyChildForm)IsFormAlreadyOpen(typeof(frmMyChildForm))) == null)
    { //Form isn't open so create one
        frmChild1= new frmMyChildForm ();

    }
   else
    { // Form is already open so bring it to the front
       frmChild1.BringToFront();

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a singleton-pattern-approach, and let the form have an Instance-member-variable that keeps track of whether it's been initialized or not.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: How would you apply this pattern in c#/winform code to satisfy the requirement of the author?

Comment: If the requirement is only one instance open at any time, and to open a new one if none are open, than this would work very well - I have in fact done this myself.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this could help you

```
Form frmToCreate;
String strClassName=typeof(FormToCreate).Name
frmToCreate = GetForm(strClass);
if(frmToCreate == null)
{
    //create the form here
}
frmToCreate.MdiParent = this; //supposing you are inside of the mainwindow (MDI window)
frmToCreate.Visible = true;
//other code goes here
```

where GetForm would be something like this

```
public Form GetForm(String type)
{
    int i;
    Form[] children = this.MdiChildren; //or mdiwindow.MdiChildren

    for (i = 0; i < children.Length; i++)
    {
        if (children[i].GetType().Name == type)
        {
            return children[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

If just a matter of playing with `MdiChildren` property.